# getting a string instead of a DateTime object (Symfony 2.8 and date form fields)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

At the moment the value being returned is in this format:

```
var_dump($form->getData());

object(DateTime)#515 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-08-03 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(18) "my-timezone-here" }
```

I just want a simple text/string value.

This is the field definition

```
->add(
    "studentdob"
    , "date"
    , array(
        "attr" => array(
                "class" => "normal"
                , "placeholder" => "YYYY-DD-MM"
        )
        , "format" => "yyyy-dd-MM"
        , "required" => false
        , "widget" => "single_text"
    )
)
```

I looked around the net and Symfony's reference pages and the only thing I can find that might be related is "data_class". But looking at examples I found in Symfony.com, I don't think this is what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how [date field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html) works in symfony. If you want a simple datetime string in your controller you should get it by like this :

```
$form->getData()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Feel free to change your date format as per your requirement!

You might want to handle the timezone. So check the `document` linked above for how to pass  `model_timezone` and `view_timezone` to the field type.

Comment: is there a way to get somethig like $form->getData()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')  ...->...  localizeddate('long', 'none', app.request.locale ), if you know what I mean.